# Why is my left padding missing inside this inline css?

Tags: html, css, inline-styles

I am trying to add a responsive html email to send to the user a link to reset their password. The left padding is not working and I would like it to be responsive like the right side, to have the container always centered.

What line of code is missing inside my inline css for my left padding to perform?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" />
    <title>StackOverflow</title>
    <style>
      /*
      //  MARK: Styling
      */
      .button {
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-family: -apple-system-body, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
        color: white;
        padding: 12px 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .buttonPassword {
        margin: auto;
      }
      #buttonReset {
        width: 150px;
        margin: auto;
        font-family: -apple-system-body, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 6px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      body {
        position: relative;
        margin: 16;
        font-family: -apple-system-body, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
      }
      .container {
        display: block;
        margin: 16 auto !important;
        max-width: 580px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 580px;
      }
      .content {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: block;
        margin: 16 auto;
        max-width: 580px;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      footer {
        width: 100%;
        font-family: -apple-system-caption2, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
      }
      header {
        margin: auto;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 100;
        top: 0;
      }
      html, body {
        min-height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 16;
        padding: 16;
      }
      .logo h1 {
        font-family: -apple-system-large-title, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
        display: inline;
      }
      .logo img {
        padding: 16px;
        width: 64px;
        height: 64px;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      p {
        font-family: -apple-system-body, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
      }
      .preheader {
        color: transparent;
        display: none;
        height: 0;
        max-height: 0;
        max-width: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        mso-hide: all;
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 0;
      }
      .right h2 {
        font-family: -apple-system-caption2, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1em;
      }
      /*
      //  MARK: Screen Sizing
      */
      @media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
        .logo h1 {
          display: inline;
        }
        .logo img {
          padding: 8px;
          width: 48px;
          height: 48px;
          vertical-align: middle;
        }
        table[class=body] .content {
          padding: 0 !important;
        }
        table[class=body] .container {
          padding: 0 !important;
          width: 100% !important;
        }
      }
      /*
      //  MARK: Colors Declaration
      //  Light Mode
      */
      .button {
        background-color: #FF9000;
      }
      #buttonReset {
        background-color: #FF9000;
      }
      .content {
        color: #000;
      }
      header {
        background: linear-gradient(#FF9000, #FFA101);
      }
      .logo h1 {
        color: #FFF;
      }
      .preheader {
        color: transparent;
      }
      .right h2 {
        color: #FFF;
      }
      /*
      //  Dark Mode
      */
      @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
        .button {
          background-color: #FF9A0A;
        }
        .content {
          color: #FFF;
        }
        header {
          background: linear-gradient(#FF9A0A, #FF9000);
        }
        .logo h1 {
          color: #FFF;
        }
        .preheader {
          color: transparent;
        }
        .right h2 {
          color: #000;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="preheader">
    Email with instructions to reset your password.
    </span>
    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="container">
          <header>
            <div class="logo">
              <h1><img src="/images/logo.png" alt="logo">StackOverflow</h1>
            </div>
          </header>
          <div id="content">
            <br>
            <p>
              Hello,
              <br><br>
              A request has been received to change the password for your StackOverlfow account.
              <br><br><br>
            <p>
            <center>
              <p>
                Click the link below to reset your password.
              <p>
              </p>
            </center>
            </p>
            </p>
            <br>
            <div class="buttonPassword">
              <center>
                <a class="button" href="#(link)">
                <strong>Reset password</strong>
                </a>
              </center>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>
              The link has a validity of one hour. Ask for a new one after this delay.
              <br>
              If you did not initiate this request, please contact us immediately at <a href="mailto:contact@stackoverflow.eu">contact@stackoverflow.eu</a> and ignore this
              email.
            </p>
            <br>
            <p>
              Thank you,
              <br>
              The StackOverlfow Team
            </p>
            <br>
          </div>
          <footer>
            <div class="right">
              <center>
                <p>© 2021 StackOverlfow. All right reserved.</p>
              </center>
            </div>
          </footer>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: typo error you forgot `px` like `margin: 16 auto !important;`  found 3 or 4 times in your css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `align="center"` on `table`

```
<table role="presentation" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/fgw258dr/

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**
You can make your container centered for every screen and responsive by just changing your container class margin with (0 auto) which centers the div automatically.

```
 .container {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto !important;
        max-width: 580px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 580px;
      }
```

Watch the final result on my [code_pen](https://codepen.io/Aqib_2000/pen/XWpYyNJ)

**Solution 2:**
simply add align=center in your table tag.